# How to pass data between pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a calendar web app with daily to-do lists. So when clicking on the link on any day, the user should be able to add and edit what to do for that day. But I would also like to show the total number of to-dos added for each day in the calendar page. E.g. 1 To-Do: "show total numbers of to-dos for this day"

I tried calling `todos.length` from localstorage, but it always shows 0.

App.jsx:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Calendar from './components/Calendar';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Calendar + To-Do-List Project</h1>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Calendar />} />
          <Route path="/todo/:day" element={<TodoList />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Calendar.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './calendar.css';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Day = ({ number, id }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`todos-${id}`)) || []);
  return (
    <div className="day">
      {number} <Link to={`/todo/${number}`}> To-Do: {todos.length} </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

const Calendar = () => {
  const now = moment();
  const daysInMonth = now.daysInMonth();
  const monthStart = now.startOf('month').day() === 0 ? 7 : now.startOf('month').day();
  const weeks = [];

  let week = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < monthStart; i++) {
    week.push(null);
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    week.push(i);
    if (week.length === 7) {
      weeks.push(week);
      week = [];
    }
  }
  if (week.length > 0) {
    while (week.length < 7) {
      week.push(null);
    }
    weeks.push(week);
  }

  const dayNames = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

  return (
    <div className="calendar-container">
      <div className="calendar-header">
        {now.format('MMMM YYYY')}
      </div>
      <div className="calendar-days">
        <div className="calendar-week">
          {dayNames.map((dayName) => (
            <div key={`day-${dayName}`} className="calendar-day-name">
              {dayName}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {weeks.map((week, index) => (
          <div key={`week-${index}`} className="calendar-week">
            {week.map((day) => (
              <div key={`day-${day}`} className="calendar-day">
                {day && <Day number={day} id={day} />}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default Calendar;
```

ToDoList.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './TodoList.css';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const TodoList = () => {
  const {day} = useParams();
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`todos-${day}`)) || []);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const [todoEditing, setTodoEdit] = useState(null);
  const [editingText, setEditText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const json = JSON.stringify(todos);
    localStorage.setItem(`todos-${day}`, json);
  }, [todos, day]);

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      text: todo,
      completed: false,
    };
    setTodos([...todos].concat(newTodo));
    setTodo("");
  };

  const toggleCompleted = (id) => {
    let updatedTodos = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  };

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    let updatedTodos = [...todos].filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  };

  const submitEdits = (id) => {
    const updatedTodos = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.text = editingText;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
    setTodoEdit(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="todo-list-container">
      <div align='right'>
        <NavLink to='/' style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}}><button > Back to Calendar </button></NavLink>
      </div>
      <h2 className="todo-list-header">To-Dos for Today</h2>        
      <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={todo}
          onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul className="todo-list">
      {todos.map((todo) => (
          <div key={todo.id} >
            <div >
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id="completed"
                checked={todo.completed}
                onChange={() => toggleCompleted(todo.id)}
              />
              {todo.id === todoEditing ? (
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setEditText(e.target.value)}
                />
              ) : (
                <div><span style={{ textDecoration: todo.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none' }}>{todo.text}</span></div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div >
              {todo.id === todoEditing ? (
                <button onClick={() => submitEdits(todo.id)}>Submit</button>
              ) : (
                <button onClick={() => setTodoEdit(todo.id)}>Edit</button>
              )}
              <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.

The solution to my problem was to edit the return statement of my Calendar.jsx.

Before:

```
{day && <Day number={day} id={now.set('date', day).format('YYYY-MM-DD')} />}
```

After:

```
{day && <Day number={day} id={day} />}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your localStorage item with these IDs: `todos-${id}` but in your App you get them via `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')`.

Hence, the ID is not the same, there can't be any data. If you check your site using the dev-tools (F12) you can actually see the contents of your localStorage by item.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't solve my problem unfortunately. I just found out that the line in my App is completely irrelevant so I deleted it entirely. At least I could see in my dev-tools that the todo items will get saved under the key "todos-{number of the day, e.g. 1}".

Comment: Glad I could be of (some) help :) If you edit your code please edit the post accordingly, otherwise others can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need to return a function as default value for `todos` state, `JSON.parse()` returns a `string`.

`todos` state into your `App.jsx` is also redundant.

Your issue is at `Day` component, your are pushing to your other route the day while trying to get the item from `localStorage` with the `id`.

Hope it helps... :)